# Prevent Atom from adding end of file newlines for certain file extensions

Tags: atom-editor

I have this in my `config.cson`:

```
".java.source":
  whitespace:
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false
".plain.text":
  whitespace:
    removeTrailingWhitespace: false
```

It works for `.java` files and `.txt` files. However, I also want it to work for specific file extensions that I don't have a scope name for.

E.g. when I edit a `.foobar` file, Atom treats it as plain text. However, it still adds a trailing newline. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a syntax to your custom file type, then your previous configuration will work for them.

**Example**

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.js": [
        "*.foobar"
      ]
```